# discord.js embedMsg not defined?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello Im trying to make a discord bot that once you click the reaction added to its embedded message, it will respond with a message depending on which one you click, One for Yes, One for No.

Everything looks fine but when I run my command I get back const collector = embedMsg.message
embedMsg not defined.
I have tried everything, so i'm thankful to any type of help I can get

Here is my code:

```
const {Client, RichEmbed} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();
client.once('ready', () => {
   console.log('dance time');

client.on('message', message => {
if(message.author.bot)
{
if(message.embeds)
{
   const embedMsg= message.embed.find(msg => msg.title === 'Boogie Time!?');
   if(embedMsg)
   {
       embedMsg.message.react('✅')
       .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('❌'))

       .catch(error => console.error);
   }
}
return;

}
   // Do this after you've added reactions

// This is filter, this specified which reactions it should capture, you can use filter to make sure you're only catching specific reactions by specific user
const filter = (reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '❌') && user.id === message.author.id;

// Here, we're defining a collector that will be active for 30 seconds and collect reactions that pass the above filter
const collector = embedMsg.message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 30000});

// This event is emitted when a reaction passes through the filter
collector.on('collect', r => r.name === '✅' ? console.log('Reacted Yes') : console.log('Reacted No'));

if(message.content.toLowCase() === 'boogie')
{
   const embed = new RichEmbed();
   embed.setTitle("Boogie Time!?")
   embed.setColor("GREEN")
   embed.setDescription("Are you sure?")
   message.channel.send(embed);
}
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the fist problem in your code its `client.on('ready'` block you end him after `client.on('message'` block. Right way is:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
   console.log('dance time');
})
```

`message.embeds` its collection array, so you need to use

```
const embedMsg = message.embeds.find(msg => msg.title === 'Boogie Time!?');
```

For the best readability of the code, try not to use `if(somethink) then do somethink`
The better way its `if(!somethink) return;`

This will allow you to get rid of a large number of brackets. In your code you try to await reaction, Regardless is this message have embeds or not. And you stop your function after add reaction with `return`, so collector will be never work.

When you const a collector you dont need you `embedMSG.message` because find method already return a message.

So you code must be like this

```
    const {Client, RichEmbed} = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Client();
    client.once('ready', () => {
       console.log('dance time');
    })
    client.on('message', message => {

      if(!message.author.bot || !message.embeds) return
      const embedMsg = message.embeds.find(embed => embed.title === 'Boogie Time!?');
      if(!embedMsg) return

      embedMsg.react('')
            .then(() => message.react(''))
            .catch(() => console.error('One of the emojis failed to react.'));

    // This is filter, this specified which reactions it should capture, you can use filter to make sure you're only catching specific reactions by specific user
    const filter = (reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.name === '?' || reaction.emoji.name === '?') && user.id === message.author.id;

    // Here, we're defining a collector that will be active for 30 seconds and collect reactions that pass the above filter

    // This event is emitted when a reaction passes through the filter
    collector.on('collect', r => r.name === '?' ? console.log('Reacted Yes') : console.log('Reacted No'));

      if(message.content.toLowCase() === 'boogie'){
         const embed = new RichEmbed();
         embed.setTitle("Boogie Time!?")
         embed.setColor("GREEN")
         embed.setDescription("Are you sure?")
         message.channel.send(embed);
      }
  })
```